# Problem creating the TEXMFHOME directory

Tags: texmf

I would like to install a template package and the instructions given by the developer include using the command prompt with the following code

```
mkdir "$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/"
```

what happens now is that in my user directory a new folder named "$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)" is created. Inside that folder is the folder "tex", inside which is the folder "latex".
I am pretty sure that is not intended, but I have no idea why this happens and how to get to the intended point in the instructions.
My operating system is Win10 and I have TexLive2015 installed.
For those curious about the instructions or the template, [here you go](https://github.com/evanbergeron/DND-5e-LaTeX-Template).

Comment: Is that a Linux command, or a Windows command? Does the developer say?

Comment: That’s bash syntax; I’m not sure it works in Windows command shell. See https://superuser.com/q/289344

Comment: It appears the developer thinks it's universal. He states the different locations on different OS, then just gives you the command without saying where to put the command.

Comment: I will try installing the windows developer mode which apparently allows the use of bash commands, or so I have read. I will report how it went.

Comment: Bash environment cannot mingle with the windows environment, developer mode did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open cmd.exe, type `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` and you'll get the path of your (users) texmf-tree, something like »C:\Users\flypirat\texmf«. Open the explorer (usually Win+e), navigate to this path and create a folder named `tex`, open the folder, create a folder `latex` and proceed.

I'm on Windows 8.1, but probably it will work on WinX as well.

Comment: I used the command you told me and cmd.exe points me to a weird location: "c:/users/flypirat/texmf". I say weird because in this case, it uses forward slashes instead of the backslashes I am used to concerning PC locations.  
Also, the folder is not there. I have the view hidden locations activated, for example, I see my AppData folder, but there is no texmf folder.

Comment: @flypirat Sorry, you should not write »flypirate«, but your username on windows, of course. And slashes are ok. And if there is no folder texmf, just create it as well. In the end, all you need is »C:/Users/yourUsername/texmf/tex/latex«, with slashes or backslashes doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, yes, I used my windows username on my PC, just using flypirat for clarity here.  
I will try creating the folder and see how the rest of the instructions, on the website I linked, go.  
If the folder is all I need, what are the other commands doing? Like the kpsewhich and the -var and so on?

Comment: @flypirat The command you printed in your question does it all in one step: Find out the path of your texmf-home and create the necessary folder with only one command. That is nice, but not worth the pain. You made two steps: find the path, create the folders.

Comment: I did it now all like you said and it seems to work. Thank you!